# File SQL to persistence nativequery UTF8

Tags: java, sql, encoding, persistence, nativequery

I create a file sql from multiple query and I run file into my app, but the special character encoding fail!
My code:

```
InputStream fis = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/myapp/patch/file.sql");
String sql = getStringFromInputStream(fis);
et.begin();
em.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
et.commit();
```

Cumps

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: the text to save database is "Franþais" instead of "Français"

Comment: What does `getStringFromInputStream()` do?

Comment: it is the funcation:

BufferedReader br = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
 try {
       br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(line);
 }
 return sb.toString();